# Icon in the menu is not clickable - Tried with positive relative and z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a calculator similar to MS window's.
When you click on the menu icon, the menu should transition from the left (where is covered) to the calculator (above the buttons).

I have tried with position relative and z-index.

**The issue I have is that once the menu is moved, the icon is still there but not clickable.**

**I set the "div menu" to stay behind its parent with z-index -2, and the gridcalculation with z-index -3. It would work if it wasn't for the fact that the icon menu is not clickable anymore.**

**Furthermore, I have a small issue with the layout: the div menu stretches out a little bit from it's container (at the bottom). I fixed it with an overflow hidden. But I don't understand why it stretches out**

```css
   

 body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: #100E17;
}


h1 {
  text-align: end;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: white;
}


h2 {
  color:#FF8A00
}


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}


.container {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
}


.leftside {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
}


.menu h3, .menu ul {
  position: relative;
  top: 2.6rem;
}


.wrapper {
  width: 15rem;
  background-color:  #100E17;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}


.menu {
  background-color: #2e3757;
  color: #FF8A00;
  width: 13rem;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}


.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.gridcalculations {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0.313rem;
}


div.icon h2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.gridcalculations i {
  
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}



.gridoperaions {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 3.75rem);
  column-gap: 0.3125rem;
  row-gap: 0.3125rem;
}


@keyframes fadein {
  from {left:0rem;}
  to {left: 13rem;}
}


@keyframes fadeout {
  from {left:13rem;}
  to {left: 0rem;}
}


.fadein {
  left:15rem;
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function:linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


.fadeout {
  left:0rem;
  animation-name: fadeout;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function:linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


.savebuttons {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}


.saves {
  flex-basis: 19.5%;
  height: 3rem;
  color:#FF8A00;
  background-color: #100E17;
}


button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}


.savebuttons button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(42, 36, 65);
}


button.number {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}


button.operator  {
  background-color:#8EE4AF;
}


button[value="="] {
  background-color: #379683;
}


button.number:hover, button.operator:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.8);
}


.rightside {
  border-left: 0.125rem #FF8A00 solid;
  margin-left: 1.2rem;
  color:#FF8A00;
}


.rightside nav li{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 0.125rem solid transparent;
}


.rightside nav li:hover {
  border-bottom: 0.125rem solid #FF8A00;
}


.rightside nav ul{
  display: flex;
}


.rightside nav li {
  margin: 0.625rem;
}


.historymenu ul li h2,
.historymenu ul li h3,
.savetab ul li h2,
.savetab ul li h3{
  text-align: right;
}

.savetab button {
  background-color: #8EE4AF;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2rem;
  visibility: hidden;
}


.savetab ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(18, 18, 29);
}

.savetab ul li:hover button{
  visibility: visible;
}


.savetab ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0;
}

.savetab ul li{
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" id="container">
      <div class="leftside" id="leftside">
        <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
        <div class="menu" id="menu">
          <h3>Calculator</h3>
          <ul>
            <li class="standard" id="standard">Standard</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li class="science" id="science">Science</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li class="datecalc" id="datecalc">Date calculation</li>
          </ul>
          <h3>Converter</h3>
          <ul>
            <li class="currency" id="currency">Currency</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li class="length" id="length">Length</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li class="weight" id="weight">Weight</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li class="temperature" id="temperature">Temperature</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="gridcalculations">
          <div class="icon"><h2><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>Standard</h2></div>
          <h1 class="display" id="display">1250</h1>
          <div class="savebuttons" id="savebuttons">
            <button class="saves" value="mc">MC</button>
            <button class="saves" value="mr">MR</button>
            <button class="saves" value="m+">M+</button>
            <button class="saves" value="m-">M-</button>
            <button class="saves" value="ms">MS</button>
          </div>
          <div class="gridoperaions" id="operations">
            <button class="operator" value="%">%</button>
            <button class="operator" value="ce">CE</button>
            <button class="operator" value="c">C</button>
            <button class="operator" value="x">X</button>
            <button class="operator" value="1/x">1/x</button>
            <button class="operator" value="x2">x2</button>
            <button class="operator" value="√">√</button>
            <button class="operator" value="÷">÷</button>
            <button class="number" value="7">7</button>
            <button class="number" value="8">8</button>
            <button class="number" value="9">9</button>
            <button class="operator" value="X">X</button>
            <button class="number" value="4">4</button>
            <button class="number" value="5">5</button>
            <button class="number" value="6">6</button>
            <button class="operator" value="-">-</button>
            <button class="number" value="1">1</button>
            <button class="number" value="2">2</button>
            <button class="number" value="3">3</button>
            <button class="operator" value="+">+</button>
            <button class="number plusminus" value="+/-">+/-</button>
            <button class="number" value="0">0</button>
            <button class="number" value=",">,</button>
            <button class="operator" value="=">=</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside" id="rightside">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>History</li>
            <li>Memory Value</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="historymenu" id="historymenu" hidden>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h3>16 + 4 =</h3>
              <h2>20</h2>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h3>10 + 6 =</h3>
              <h2>16</h2>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h3>5 + 5 =</h3>
              <h2>10</h2>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="savetab" id="savetab">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h2>20</h2>
              <h3>
                <span><button class="btnsave" value="mc">MC</button></span>
                <span><button class="btnsave" value="m+">M+</button></span>
                <span><button class="btnsave" value="m-">M-</button></span>
              </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h2>30</h2>
              <h3>
                <span><button class="btnsave" value="mc">MC</button></span>
                <span><button class="btnsave" value="m+">M+</button></span>
                <span><button class="btnsave" value="m-">M-</button></span>
              </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h2>40</h2>
              <h3>
                <span><button class="btnsave" value="mc">MC</button></span>
                <span><button class="btnsave" value="m+">M+</button></span>
                <span><button class="btnsave" value="m-">M-</button></span>
              </h3>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: I created a snippet, could you please specify where's the menu icon?

Comment: The icon should be at the top left close to "standard". I am not sure why it does not show up. I run my code and it does appear.

Comment: Can you put your code in a jsfiddle like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/danielware/2m3kurg4/ or this? http://jsfiddle.net/igambin/MumBN/ or this? https://jsfiddle.net/ItayGrudev/KGtbU/ or this? http://jsfiddle.net/w72vM/80/

Comment: Is this the code that shows up nowhere on the screen that you can see? <h2><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>Standard</h2>

Comment: Yes, I edited the code, now it should be visible. I used postive z-index. A bit better, but I cannot hide the menu list now behind the wrapper.